# Port connection not working

Tags: java, sockets, http, server, client

Implementing a java program for creating a socket for HTTP for Webpage upload and Download. I wrote a server side program ans client program. when i run the program it says Native port problem.

Server.Java

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Server {



    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {


    ServerSocket server= null;
    Socket socket;
    server=new ServerSocket(4000);
    System.out.println("Server waiting for image");
    socket=server.accept();
    System.out.println("Client Connected");
    InputStream in=socket.getInputStream();
    DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(in);
    int len=dis.readInt();
    System.out.println("Image size:"+len/1024+"kb");
    byte[] data=new byte[len];
    dis.readFully(data);
    dis.close();
    in.close();
    InputStream ian=new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    BufferedImage bImage=ImageIO.read(ian);
    JFrame f=new JFrame("server");
    ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(bImage);
    JLabel l=new JLabel();
    l.setIcon(icon);
    f.add(l);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);



    }

}
```

Client.Java

```
package javaapplication1;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
/**
 *
 * @author Mohamed
 */
public class Client {


    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {


      Socket soc;
      BufferedImage img= null;
      soc=new Socket("localhost",4000);
      System.out.println("Client running");
       try

         {
                System.out.println("Reading image from disk");
        img=ImageIO.read(new File("blue.jpg"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(img,"jpg",baos);
        baos.flush();
        byte[] bytes=baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
        System.out.println("Sending image to server");
        OutputStream out=soc.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(out);
        dos.writeInt(bytes.length);
        dos.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
        System.out.println("Image sent to server");
        dos.close();
        out.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception:"+e.getMessage());
        soc.close();
    }
     soc.close();
    }
}
```

And the error for the Client.Java is in the Image below [Error message for the code Client.Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqkEb.png)

What the actual out should be when the code is excuted in Command Prompt is as follows

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.1.6.0_21\bin>javac Server.java
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.1.6.0_21\bin>java Server
Server waiting for image
Client connected
Image size:27kb

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.1.6.0_21\bin>javac Client.java
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.1.6.0_21\bin>java Client
Client is running
Reading image from disk
Sending Image to server
Image sent to the server 
<And the image is displayed>
```

Please tell me what is the error or leave a comment with correct code. Thank you!

Comment: Define 'it says Native port problem'. 'Connection refused' means nothing was listening.

Comment: I see the console result,it means the client receive data and the server send data successfully.So when does the error `Connection refused` happens.